# React JS - Tabs - Como deixar o primeiro aberto por default através do estado?

Tags: javascript, react, react-navigation

Tenho o seguinte componente que monta tabs na página:

```
// * Components
// * Natives
import { useState } from 'react';

// * Render
export default function Accordeon(props){

    const data = props.data;

    // * Set States
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(null);
    const toggleExpanded = (id) => () => setIsExpanded((isExpanded) => (isExpanded === id ? null : id));

    // * Render
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {props.data.map((data, index) => {

                    return (
                        <li key={index} isexpanded={isExpanded === data.id}>
                            <a onClick={toggleExpanded(data.id)}>{data.title}</a>
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
            <div>
                {props.data.map((data, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className={(isExpanded === data.id ? '' : 'hidden') + ''}>
                             data.description
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Ele recebe um objeto como props, e através dele, executo um map e a montagem acontece.
Um exemplo de map:

```
const accordeonData = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'Teste',
        'description': 'Conteudo 01',
        'active': true
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'Teste 2',
        'description': 'Conteudo 02'
    }
];
```

Eu crio um estado com valor null, e quando eu clico para exibir uma das tabs, o estado recebe o valor do ID.

Porém, estou tentando passar um default, para que sempre tenhamos um em aberto.
Já tentei trocar o null pelo ID que tem o parametro "active", sem sucesso.

Já tentei disparar o toggleExpanded() quando `data.active === true`, também sem sucesso (neste caso, ele ainda diz que o react entra num loop e para a execução).

Ex:

```
props.data.map((data) => {
    if(data.active === true){
        setIsExpanded(data.id);
    }
})
```

Como posso adaptar meu código para que seja possível ter um aberto por default, ou seja, quando no map, passar por um objeto que tenha active: true, ou o toggleExpanded seja disparado, liberando o ID para visualização, ou de qualquer outra maneira viável?

Estou empacado nesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao meu ver trocar `null` pelo id do estado que possui o parametro active definido como `true` deveria funcionar, perceba que nesse seu código o `null` atua como um valor padrão, pq quando nenhum id está com toggle ativado, `null` é setado no estado `isExpanded` o que significa que nenhum deve estar em exibição, sendo esse o padrão para esse caso.

Acho que o problema está na maneira em como vc tentou usar essa solução (apesar disso não ter sido mostrado). Veja abaixo uma possível solução para o que vc pensou, usando o hook `useEffect` do React:

```js
// * Components
// * Natives
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Accordeon(props) {
  const data = props.data;
  const [defaultV, setDefaultV] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    for (let elem of data) {
      if (elem.active) {
        setDefaultV(elem.id);
        setIsExpanded(elem.id);
        break;
      }
    }
  }, [data]);

  // * Set States

  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(null);
  const toggleExpanded = (id) =>
    setIsExpanded((isExpanded) => (isExpanded === id ? defaultV : id));

  // * Render
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {props.data.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index} isexpanded={isExpanded === data.id}>
              <button onClick={() => toggleExpanded(data.id)}>
                {data.title}
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <div>
        {props.data.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              className={(isExpanded === data.id ? "" : "hidden") + ""}
            >
              {data.description}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Neste caso o hook `useEffect` funciona como o método `componentDidMount` em Componentes de Classe, ou seja, a arrow function contida no primeiro parâmetro de useEffect só é executada quando todo o componente for renderizado, encontrando o elemento com active definido e o setando como default através do estado `defaultV`

Espero que minha interpretação sobre seu problema seja realmente o que vc quer.

Comment: Identifiquei alguns outros problemas em seu código e corrigi

Comment: muito bom! O UseEffect resolveu a charada. Não sabia deste comportamento dele ser executado quanto tudo já foi renderizado! Muito legal mesmo! Resolvido!